# .reduce in lodash fucntionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to figure out whether all three objects are defined or not in a optimized and less code. For that purpose, I'm using `lodash` with `reduce`. But It is not giving me the correct value. Am I using reduce in a wrong way ?

```
checker1 = ((level1.test[testState.Id]['p1']['o1'] == undefined) && 
(level1.test[testState.Id]['p1']['o2'] == undefined) && 
(level1.test[testState.Id]['p1']['o3'] == undefined))
console.log('checker',checker1) //true


checker2 = _.reduce(level1.test[testState.Id] ,
                            (checker, val) => {return checker || (val == undefined)}, false)                  
console.log('checker',checker2) //false! It should be true!
```

Answer (score 4):

It'd be easier (and more performant, as it has early-exit properties) to use `Array.every`:

```
const obj = level1.test[testState.Id].p1;
const checker1 = ['o1', 'o2', 'o3'].every(key => obj[key] === undefined);
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX can we use lodash for this ?

Comment: Lodash also has `every`, yes.

Comment: Then when should we use .every and .reduce ?

Comment: When you don't want or need to use Lodash?

Answer (score 1):

Your input to `_.reduce` is just `level1.test[testState.Id]`, which seems to be a non-array object. Nothing in that code tells `_.reduce` it would work on the `.p1.o1`, `.p1.o2`, and `.p1.o3` properties on the object.

If you want to use `reduce` for this, I'd use the native one and start with an array of property names:

```
checker2 = ['o1', 'o2', 'o3'].reduce(
    (checker, prop) => checker && level1.test[testState.Id].p1 === undefined,
    false
);
```

> ... in a optimized and less code

`reduce` doesn't do either of those things. It requires creating an array and multiple function calls. Instead:

```
const obj = level1.test[testState.id].p1;
checker = obj.o1 === undefined && obj.o2 === undefined && obj.o3 === undefined;
```

(If you *are* going to use an array and callbacks, use `every` as [AKX points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756354/157247).)

Comment: thanks @T.J. Crowder ! Can we use lodash for this ?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Sure, just change `['o1', 'o2', 'o3'].reduce(` to `_.reduce(['o1', 'o2', 'o3'],`. But there's no reason to other than style (whereas if you use the native form, *maybe* the JavaScript engine can optimize it better). Similarly, to use AKX's `every` answer, you'd do `_.every([['o1', 'o2', 'o3'],`.